# Client connected event outside of SignalR hub

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am looking for a simple way to notify code that is outside of the SignalR hub about a new client connection.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Dependency Injection](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/advanced/dependency-injection) in your hub class.
One [IoC Container](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) easy to integrate with SignalR is [Autofac](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

```
public class NotifyHub : Hub
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _hubLifetimeScope;
    private readonly IHubService _hubService;

    public NotifyHub(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
    {
        // Create a lifetime scope for the hub.
        _hubLifetimeScope = lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope("AutofacWebRequest");

        // Resolve dependencies from the hub lifetime scope.
        _hubService = _hubLifetimeScope.Resolve<IHubService>();
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        //Or whatever you want to send
        _hubService.CustomNotify(name, Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // Dipose the hub lifetime scope when the hub is disposed.
        if (disposing && _hubLifetimeScope != null)
        {
            _hubLifetimeScope.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Also, you need to [provide dependency injection integration for SignalR hubs](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/signalr.html):

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
//other IoC registrations
builder.RegisterType(typeof(HubService)).As(typeof(IHubService)).InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<GaugeHub>().ExternallyOwned();

var container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new Autofac.Integration.SignalR.AutofacDependencyResolver(container);
```